# How to show maths formulas and equations in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I researched on this for quite a while and I know this kind of questions already answered. But I couldn't find a right answer showing how to practically deal with math formula in Android app in xamarin.

Formulas and equations are fetching from database.

Comment: Do you want to simply display them or do they need to be interactive?

Comment: I just want to display them simple.

Comment: @Shashankshandilya I would use a WebView along with a JavaScript library (like `MathJax` or `jqMath`) but there are a number of Java-based libraries that you could use via an `Xamarin.Android` Binding library, most of them are centered around MathML. There are also full Android app examples on the web.....

Comment: "how to practically deal with math formula ". Define "deal with". This is so vague it could mean anything.

Comment: \(\sim r\Rightarrow \sim p\vee q\) formula like this fetched from database and now I want to show this formula in proper format in xamarin?